# For each linear transformation $L\colon V \to W$ , find the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to the standard bases for $V$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I need help with (part c of) the following question.

> For each linear transformation $L:V \to W$, find the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to the standard bases of $V$ and $W$.
>
> c)  $L:P_3 \to P_3$, $L(p(x)) = p''(x) + xp'(x) + p(x)$, with respect to the standard basis $E = \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ for $P_3$.

So my first guess is to take the derivative of $x^3$  , $2$ times, then once and get $6x + x(3x^2) + x^3 $. That column of the matrix would be $(0, 6, 0, 4)^T $. Then I'd do the same thing for $x^2$, $x$ and $1$. Does this seem correct?

[Here's my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9qUh.jpg). To summarize,
$$
L(1) = 1, \quad 
L(x) = 2x, \quad 
L(x^2) = 2 + 3x^2, \quad
L(x^3) = 6x + 4x^3 \implies\\
[L]_E = 
\pmatrix{
1&0&2&0\\
0&2&0&6\\
0&0&3&0\\
0&0&0&4}.
$$

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work and your answer are completely correct.

Comment: Thanks for verifying this!